# How to get the Qty left in stock of a particular product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1.3, qty

anybody can suggest me that how can i display the left quantity in stock of a particular product in product details page ?. I am using Magento 2.1.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want for all products then you can use `Only X left Threshold` Configuration option from `Store > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory`. If you set the Qty `20` and If your product Qty is less than 20 then in product detail page It will display like this,

[image]

Comment: How to show this in product list page?

Comment: This doesn't work for configurable products. How to make it work for configurable products also.